# How can I use mongo changestreams and ws websockets in the same node.js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, websocket, changestream

I'm trying to write some nodejs code that works with a currently running MongoDB database by setting up a changestream and (using the [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) websocket library) forwards those changes to connected clients.

I followed [this guide](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/an-introduction-to-change-streams) to create the initial mongo changestream code, which is working:

```
conn = new Mongo("mongodb://localhost:27017/demo?replicaSet=rs");
db = conn.getDB("demo");
collection = db.stock;

const changeStreamCursor = collection.watch(
    [{
        $match: {
            $or: [
                { operationType: "update" },
                { operationType: "insert" }
            ]
        }
    }],
    {
        fullDocument: 'updateLookup'
    }
);

pollStream(changeStreamCursor);
out each change as it comes in
function pollStream(cursor) {
    while (!cursor.isExhausted()) {
        if (cursor.hasNext()) {
            change = cursor.next();
            print(JSON.stringify(change));
        }
    }
    pollStream(cursor);
}
```

I then run this file with the mongo script:

`~/Mongo/bin/mongo change-stream-socket-server.js`

So, I basically want to use this code above but add in websockets and call `ws.send()` instead of just logging the changes to the console.

The problem is, though, that it seems I can't use "require" in a javascript file being executed by the mongo script. Is there some way to have it add the ws dependency or be able to use require?

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8040 });

conn = new Mongo("mongodb://localhost:27017/");
db = conn.getDB("demo");
collection = db.stock;

const changeStreamCursor = collection.watch(
    [{
        $match: {
            $or: [
                { operationType: "update" },
                { operationType: "insert" }
            ]
        }
    }],
    {
        fullDocument: 'updateLookup'
    }
);



console.log('also setting up websockets...')

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

        wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {

        pollStream(changeStreamCursor);

        function pollStream(cursor) {

            while (!cursor.isExhausted()) {
                if (cursor.hasNext()) {
                    change = cursor.next();
                    print(JSON.stringify(change));
                    client.send(JSON.stringify(change))
                }
            }
            pollStream(cursor);
        }

    });
});

console.log('server running, waiting for connections...')
```

When I run it with mongo I get this output with an error, "require is not defined":

> MongoDB shell version v3.6.4 connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
>   MongoDB server version: 3.6.4 2018-10-28T21:23:53.515-0400 E QUERY
>   [thread1] ReferenceError: require is not defined :
>   @change-stream-socket-server.js:2:7 failed to load:
>   change-stream-socket-server.js

If I try to just run it with "node" and the file, I get an error that Mongo is not defined. I tried to connect to it using "MongoClient" with the code below, but this did not work for me either.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const dbName = 'demo';
const client = new MongoClient(url);

client.connect(function(err) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");

    const db = client.db('demo');

    const changeStreamCursor = db.collection('stock').watch();

    pollStream(changeStreamCursor);

    function pollStream(cursor) {
    while (!cursor.isExhausted()) {
        if (cursor.hasNext()) {
            change = cursor.next();
            print(JSON.stringify(change));
        }
    }
    pollStream(cursor);
}

});
```

This above code gives me the output with an error saying, "cursor.isExhausted is not a function":

> (node:4590) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is
>   deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new
>   parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
>   Connected successfully to server
>   /Users/jim/Git-Projects/MongoDB-Change-Streams-Example/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:466
>         throw err;
>         ^
>
> TypeError: cursor.isExhausted is not a function
>       at pollStream (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/MongoDB-Change-Streams-Example/basic-mongo-changesream-watcher.js:68:17)
>       at /Users/jim/Git-Projects/MongoDB-Change-Streams-Example/basic-mongo-changesream-watcher.js:47:2
>       at result (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/MongoDB-Change-Streams-Example/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:414:17)
>       at executeCallback (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/MongoDB-Change-Streams-Example/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:406:9)
>       at err (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/MongoDB-Change-Streams-Example/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:286:5)
>       at connectCallback (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/MongoDB-Change-Streams-Example/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:241:5)
>       at process.nextTick (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/MongoDB-Change-Streams-Example/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:463:7)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Is there any way for me to be able to use Mongo changestreams and the ws websocket library together? Thanks!

Comment: I think you're on the right track running it in node. Check out the documentation for using a change stream in node: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/ChangeStream.html

Comment: Also check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/ which has node.js example code.

Comment: thanks. is there a specific server mongo library I can install to access the changestreams in node?

Comment: @Jim you would need to use the MongoDB node driver, access the changestream through the node driver, and output the result using a websocket library. The key thing is it needs to run under node. The `mongo` shell cannot do node-style import (although it can execute js files), and it's not designed to do a long running operation like these. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks @KevinAdistambha! Do you have any code examples that use the node driver to do this?

Comment: @Jim I don't have a fully tested example handy and I'm not very familiar with Websocket, but I presume you can follow the example code in https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/an-introduction-to-change-streams and replace `print()` with `ws.send()`.

Comment: Thanks @KevinAdistambha, but as I mentioned in the original post the mongo driver doesn't properly implement the changestream cursor.